# Why are the boxes of checkboxes absent?

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox

I am trying to create a list of filters to alter search results, but for some reason the boxes do not get rendered as seen on following image:
[checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3PG.jpg)

If I change it to a different type, such as radio, it works normally:
[radio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVj3f.jpg)

```
<h3>
                    Diet:
                </h3>
                <ul>
                        {diets.map((option) => {
                            return (
                            <li key={option.value}>
                                <label>
                                    <input
                                        type='checkbox'
                                        onChange={(e) =>
                                            handleDietsSelect(e, option.value)
                                        }
                                        checked={sidebarFormState.diets.includes(option.value)}
                                    />
                                    <span>
                                        {option.display}
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I have tried many found variations with form, fieldset, label, id/name etc. but the result remains the same: radio shows, checkbox comes without box.

Anyone any idea why my boxes aren't showing?

Comment: What do the Dev Tools show when you look at the Elements tab? Is there any CSS with a selector like `[type=checkbox]` being applied?

Comment: It looks like you posted your React (or some other framework) component, instead of the HTML. If you want help with a JavaScript framework could you add the relevant tag, or if you want HTML/CSS help please post the HTML (not the script).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I found my answer through this. In the navigation bar I also am using a checkbox and I have it hidden through the css: 
-webkit-appearance: none;
display: none;
Despite it being a different component with its own css, I suppose the css affected these checkboxes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, I don't think React has built-in style encapsulation like Angular. You need to use CSS modules to get that. Otherwise, all components share styling, so you need to be careful with your selectors.